# Struggling to use environment variables in python script when running in ansible playbook

Tags: python, ansible

I have an ansible playbook which one of its tasks is to run a python script,
This specific script uses env variables inside it.
I configured the env variables at ~/.profile file.

When I run the python script directly from the command line it runs perfectly.
when it runs as a part of the playbooks it doesn't recognize the environment variables.

my ansible task:

```
- name: Write hostname to things mobile website
  ansible.builtin.command: sudo -E python3 write_hostname_to_tm.py
  register: write_host_name_output
- debug: var=write_host_name_output.stdout_lines
```

my python script for simplicity:

```
import os
USER_NAME = os.environ.get('USER_NAME')
print(USER_NAME)
```

love for some help

thanks in advance

Comment: ansible runs a non-interactive, non login shell (sh by default) and therefore does not load `~/profile` nor any other init files for the shell (e.g. `~/bashrc`...). You either need to source your `~/profile` file in the same call or pass the environment variables to the script with an `environment` option at task or play level.